# Passing a variable to template file in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress plugin I have a function which has a page id:

```
public function create_view_for_pdf() {
        $page_id = $_POST['page_id'];
        $this->template_shortcode('template.php');
    }
```

here, "template_shortcode" function includes a template located in a folder in the plugin directory.

```
private function KendoPdf_template_shortcode($template_name) {
        return include '/template/dir' . $template_name;
    }
```

In the template file, I want to pass the page id so that I can print content there. How can I do that?

Note: Since I am just including the template file, I thought I will get the $page_id variable there normally. But it did not work. I needed the page id in template file because the content will be different than the actual page. That page also has ACF fields. I am basically creating a new template for pdf export. That's why I cannot use all the content of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong but why would you pass the the page_id to the template file if it is within `$_POST`? Just access the variable using `$_POST['page_id'];` within your template file.

Instead of including your template file you could also read it into a string with `file_get_contents();` and do your desired replacements before you return it.

Another possibility would be a global variable which is already set: `global $post;`

And last but not least you could use output buffering with `ob_start();` (and consecutive functions).

You see: A lot of ways to solve this.

Comment: Since I am just including the template file, I thought I will get the $page_id variable there normally. But it did not work. I needed the page id in template file because the content is different than the actual page. That page also has ACF fields. I am basically creating a new template for pdf export. Thats why I cannot use all the content of that page.

Comment: @Imrul.H Sure but why can you not use one of the methods I have described here?

Comment: I tried both of the other solutions, did not work. I tried this it in the template file: global $post;
echo 'post id:'.$post->ID;
which did not work. then I also tried using ob_start() and ob_get_clean() before and after the template inclusion. this did not help either.

Comment: Can you try with a custom global? Before including the template do the following: `$page_id = $_POST['page_id']; global $template_page_id = $page_id;`  .... then within the template do: `global $template_page_id; echo $template_page_id;`

Comment: It worked! But there is a slight change. Before including the file: ::code::global $pdf_page_id; $pdf_page_id = $_POST['page_id'];::code end::. Code for template file is exactly like your example. Thanks a lot :)